# Rails 3 - Model Error Message Validation Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Currently I have a script that checks to make sure that a test card was not submitted in production (since Authorize.net accepts test credit cards in live mode) and I add an error message to the credit card number if the one submitted is in the `Test_Credit_Cards` array like so:

```
TEST_CREDIT_CARDS = ['370000000000002', '6011000000000012', '4007000000027', '4012888818888']
validate :not_a_test_credit_card
 def not_a_test_credit_card
      self.errors[:cc_number] << "number is invalid!" if TEST_CREDIT_CARDS.include?(cc_number) and Rails.env.production?
    end
```

Now on the front end the error message appears like so:
`Credit card cc number is invalid!`

Is there anyway to change the message to read `Credit Card number is invalid!` I just want to remove the `cc` portion from the message.

Comment: Are you sure it is not `Credit card cc_number number is invalid` ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was a typo on my part... I just want to be able to remove the attribute from my error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the number from the error message:

```
  self.errors[:cc_number] << "is invalid!" if TEST_CREDIT_CARDS.include?(cc_number) and Rails.env.production?
```

Next, put a translation for cc_number in config/locales/en.yml:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      credit_card:
        cc_number: "number"
```

I prefer this answer over Anthony Alberto's answer for three reasons:

1. It is always a good idea to use ActiveRecord existing translation engine.
2. This way, cc_number will be translated to number whenever you add errors on it.
3. It is not true that the error is on the CreditCard instance itself, it is specifically related to the cc_number field.

Answer (score 0):

That should do it :

```
self.errors[:base] << "number is invalid!" if TEST_CREDIT_CARDS.include?(cc_number) and Rails.env.production?
```

`base` refers to the object as a whole, not a specific attribute.